# Creating array of struct inside another struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am having trouble in code:

```
typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
} Passenger;

typedef struct{
    int amount;
    Passenger bus_array[amount];
} Bus;
```

> The amount undeclared here.

Comment: No, it would not. In fact, you cannot declare such a struct because the compiler would not know how much space to reserve for it when you create an instance of it. You must use a pointer and allocate the array dynamically. You would most likely change the `amount` in a function which sets `ammount`[sic] and de-allocates the old memory and then allocates the new memory. That would be going in the direction of C++ (classes are structures of data with operations on them).

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)?

Comment: Thank you Peter, would you be so kind and help me allocate memory? i know how to use malloc for int or double data types, but no for struct data type :(

Comment: When you allocate memory with `malloc` for an array of `int`, you use `sizeof(int)` for the element size right? It's the exact same thing with structures, but the type is e.g. `struct Passanger`, which means you use `sizeof(struct Passanger)`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I didn't know about flexible array members (only about the pre-C99 hack with silently extending end-arrays). Such structs always need their space allocated dynamically, which implies among others that they cannot be in an array, right, because their `sizeof()` is wrong (hey, it's a `sizeoff()`!)? (Except with a zero size array.)

Comment: Thank you dude, where am i mistaken when allocating memory inside struct like this: struct Passanger* bus_array;
    bus_array = (struct Passanger*)malloc(ammount * sizeof(struct Passanger));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives, both involves dynamic memory allocation. The big difference is *what* structure you're allocating dynamically.

---

The first alternative is using a pointer instead of an array:

```
typedef struct{
    int amount;
    Passenger *bus_array;
} Bus;
```

Once you know the value of `amount` you can allocate memory for `bus_array`:

```
Bus my_bus;
bus.amount = get_passenger_amount();
bus.bus_array = malloc(bus.amount * sizeof(Passenger));
```

---

The second alternative is using an [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member) (as I mentioned in a comment):

```
typedef struct{
    int amount;
    Passenger bus_array[];
} Bus;
```

Then you need to allocate the `Bus` structure dynamically:

```
int amount = get_passenger_amount();

Bus *my_bus = malloc(sizeof(Bus) + amount * sizeof(Passenger));
my_bus->amount = amount;
```

---

There are some differences between the two methods that might be worth to note. The most important is that the first method makes two separate and distinct allocations: One for the `Bus` structure and another for the `bus_array`. The second method there is only a single combined allocation for all of the `Bus` structure as well as `bus_array`.

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: The struct 'Bus' from the first variant is small enough to be passed by value as parameter/return value. Thus it usually be one allocation as well

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
typedef struct{
  int amount;
  Passenger bus_array[amount];
} Bus;
```

When compiler see the below statement

```
Passenger bus_array[amount];
```

it doesn't know *how much memory to allocate for `bus_array`* because `amount` is *unknown* for compiler at this stage. Hence it throws the error.

Instead of

```
Passenger bus_array[amount];
```

you can use

```
Passenger *bus_array;
```

and later on you can allocate memory for `bus_array` equal to `amount` bytes when compiler knows what is `amount`.

Comment: Thank you! I will proceed using this method :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Achai's correct answer, and because you asked, I would allocate memory for the passengers  like this:

```
typedef struct{
  int amount;
  Passenger *bus_array;
} Bus;

Bus emptyBus = { 0, NULL}; // use this to initialize new buses so that pointer and amount are zero.

void changeAmount(Bus *bus, int amount)
{
  bus->amount = amount;
  free(bus->bus_array); // freeing a null pointer is OK.
  bus->bus_array = malloc(sizeof(Passenger)*amount);
}
```